# Spoiler-markup broken for multilined display math?

Tags: bug, mathjax, markdown, spoilers

A brief search didn't turn out a dupe, but recently I have found that the spoiler-markup `>!` doesn't work well with multilined MathJax, especially displaystyle:

```
>! $$\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\
3&4\end{pmatrix}$$
```

> ! $$\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\
> 3&4\end{pmatrix}$$

```
>! $$\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\
>! 3&4\end{pmatrix}$$
```

> ! $$\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\
> >! 3&4\end{pmatrix}$$

How can this be fixed other than putting all the MathJax in a single line wich can be very bad for long code? Also note that the centering of `$$...$$` isn't working in spoilers either during preview.

```
>! $$\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{pmatrix}$$
```

> $$\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: You might find some posts mentioning similar problems if you have a look at other posts tagged ([meta-tag:spoilers]). From example this two posts seem related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10906/big-tex-wont-get-hidden-by, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9297/how-to-put-math-equations-in-a-spoiler-block (In both cases some environment, which contained `\\`, was used.)

Comment: Why do you need spoilers?

Comment: @quid Mostly for pedagogic purposes: Leave the option for the interested asker to run through the described process himself and compare his results to the actual solutions in a spoiler. I rarely employ them (wich you might know), but there are times where I find those useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did not know how much you use them. I am glad to hear you only use them rarely, as generally I consider them to be a nuissance on this site. Most of the time I think an asker that wishes to can run the process themselves even when the result was visible to them briefly.

Comment: @quid Generally I fully agree with you, wich is why I use them very rarely. But if the solution is a very interesting one, knowing it might "bias" the mathematical intuition towards the solution, sometimes preventing mistakes one would have made had one not known the solution. (Much grammatic, very wow)

Comment: Right. But then typically that solution would be *short*, else one could not even grasp it quickly. So for multiline-spoilers this seem exceedingly rarely an issue. But I guess by this point I insist too much on this. Sorry for the noise. I just really dislike spoilers on this site.

Comment: No problem, but matrices for example (as shown above) are barely readable if put into one line even if only one line of math is rendered.

Comment: In case you're not aware, there's an environment smallmatrix for... small matrices. You need to add the brackets yourself, but they look a bit better (I think) in inline math.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I'm aware, thanks. Still their code as a one-liner is barely readable for larger matrices (or more complicated cells). I'm also aware of the shorthand `\pmatrix{...}` wich will improve readability at least a little when in one line.

Comment: IMHO, the spoiler on math.SE is so hard to use and I'll just forget it.
$$\newcommand{\myspoiler}[2][padding: 4px;]{ \style{background-color: rgb(240,240,240);#1}{\class{spoiler}{#2}}} \verb/Your matrix is hiding here/ \rightarrow \myspoiler[padding: 8px;]{
\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{pmatrix}
}$$

Comment: @achillehui While nice and working, I think that format disrupts the UI too much.